# exponential integration with fractional powers

Tags: integration, exponential-function, fractions

I am trying to solve the following integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^a \frac{\beta_1 \beta_2}{y^2(c-y)^2} e^{-\beta_1/(c-y)}  e^{-\beta_2/y} \, dy$$
where $a<0$, $c>0$, $\beta_1>0$, $\beta_2>0$

I searched the book like "Tables of integral, series.." but cannot find any formula to solve it. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: What integral?.

Comment: @AaronMaroja Sorry man, I did not know how to construct the integration before, now I put it on the page. Please check it out, thank you.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial on MathJax.